# UsageError: Line magic function `%cd..` not found

Tags: python, shell, ipython, jupyter-notebook, cd

I get the error:

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%cd..` not found.
```

when running my python code that i usually run from Jupyter Notebook through a shell command.
I use `%cd` and `%ls` all the time in Jupiter notebooks and do not get why i can not run it from shell.
I both tried:

```
python test.py
```

and

```
ipython test.py
```

this is the relevant part of my code:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import IPython
   from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
   if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
   else:
    from io import StringIO

def main():
    script = sys.argv[0]
    map_name = sys.argv[1]
    callPenalty()

def callPenalty():
    %cd standalone-penalty
    os.system("octave-cli penalty.m map_bit.bmp 50 1 1 150 150")
    %cd..
main()
```

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Try adding a space after 'cd' in 'cd..'. Shell tends to take cd.. to mean a single command, rather than a command with an argument of ..

Comment: Don't use them in Python code; just use `os.chdir` instead.

Comment: Magics like that are available in interactive `ipython` sessions.  I haven't looked into how to make them available in a script.  It probably requires importing some `ipython` module/engine.